# Siri: play all songs NOT shuffled

Tags: ios, music, siri

Does anyone know a way to ask Siri on iPhone or iPad to play an artist, but have the songs go in album order instead of shuffled?

I have tried asking "don't shuffle" and "play X in order" and also "play albums by X"...

Answer (score -1):

By default it will shuffle it, you may have better luck asking Siri to play a playlist instead.